# /testfor item in item frame help with code

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to test for a specific item in an item frame and I'm sure I have the correct code.

```
/testfor @e[type=Item_Frame,x=-1285,y=72,z=788}] {Item:{id:minecraft:leather}}
```

However I get this error:

```
[02:46:44] Data tag parsing failed: Expected '}' but got ':' at: {Item:{id:minecraft:<--[HERE]
```

This is a fairly simple code. I follow the 'mold' everyone else is using for this specific testfor command, but I get an error. There may be a different way to write it 1.12?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: @Fabian you answered with "pretty sure" and I explained it further. Go ahead and edit your answer then. I don't see a reason to answer this question twice only to describe the behavior.

Comment: Done. But why did you delete your comment? Also my two points were separate from each other: 1. Usually you could write something like that as your own answer. 2. In this case I already wrote it, so I thought you were just repeating yourself. Now that you said that you were sure where I was not, I edited my answer. But in that case it would have been better as a comment to my answer, not to the question.

Comment: Was not aware of the quotes! Thank you for pointing that out Fabian! Also, Anvil, good eye with the extra '}' in [type=Item_Frame,x=-1285,y=72,z=788}] . Somehow the code worked despite this extra curly. It was a burning question keeping me up at 2am!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had an obsolete `}` in the target selector. But probably you didn't have that in the game, because then your error message would have been different.

Your real issue: Since 1.9 you need quotes around the item ID:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item_Frame,x=-1285,y=72,z=788] {Item:{id:"minecraft:leather"}}
```

1.13 syntax:

```
/execute if entity @e[type=item_frame,x=-1285,y=72,z=788,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:leather"}} run <command>
```

You can also leave out `run` and the command if you just want a chat output.

Comment: I believe its `ItemFrame` and without that } after the z coordinate. Also it should work without the count.

Comment: 1. No, since 1.9 it's `item_frame` and capitalization doesn't matter. 2. You're correct with the `}`. In that case the error message in the question is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That error is specifically pointing to the portion the error was flagged for.

Look at this portion:

```
{Item:{id:minecraft:leather}}
```

The portion after `id:` should be in quotes, so: `{Item:{id:"minecraft:leather"}}`.  Without quotes it is trying to parse the `:` after `minecraft` as code.

So the error is telling you, it `Expected '}' but got ':'`

---

Another problem I see with the command is in the target selector

```
@e[type=Item_Frame,x=-1285,y=72,z=788}]
```

The last two characters, there is an unneeded `}` after `788`.

---

The command with both problems fixed is:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item_Frame,x=-1285,y=72,z=788] {Item:{id:"minecraft:leather"}}
```

I have tested it in a command block with a comparator output and it functions properly.